# Connect to mongodb running inside Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, virtualbox

I am using Windows 10

I have installed Virtual Box

In virtual Box I have installed Ubuntu with network setting as Bridge Network

I am using Docker Toolbox for Windows to Start Docker

In Docker I have Mongodb container running at default port

I am doing all my development stuff inside Ubuntu installed in Virtual Box

Here is my Terminal Log

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER        ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v17.06.0-ce


$ docker-machine env
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="C:\Users\test\.docker\machine\machines\default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
export COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS="true"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval $("C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env)


$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
77427d4fc49b        mongo               "/bin/sh -c '/usr/..."   About an hour ago   Up 45 minutes                           mongo
```

**Issue is I dont know how to Connect to this container running MongoDB globally say from Ubuntu running on Virtual Box**

**Edit 1:**

Terminal Log from Ubuntu

```
test@test-VirtualBox:~$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:e1:c8:be brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.27/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 78034sec preferred_lft 78034sec
    inet6 fe80::2ae9:9e0c:d9a3:f044/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:3d:79:a8:7f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Issue seems to be that you seem to be asking for a tutorial. If you want a tutorial then https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+docker+container+create is where you look. If you have a specific problem, then you show your specific problem and ask about that.

Comment: @NeilLunn I have edited my question

Comment: Why do you use docker for windows, if you already have virtualbox with ubuntu installed. It is better to run docker inside ubuntu vm.

Comment: @yamenK I know. If I use Docker Inside Ubuntu all problem solved. But as per my requirment I need to use above mentioned setup and do some changed in Network Adapter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run your mongo container with port mappings

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 mongodb
```

And then you can access using `192.168.99.100:27017`.

**Edit-1**

If you are connect it from another VM then make sure to add an adapter with common Host-only network lan. In most cases this would `vboxnet1`

[image: Network Settings]

And configure the network as below for your Ubuntu VM (make sure both docker VM and Ubuntu VM use the same)

[image: VM Settings]

Comment: I am able to access mongo in Docker Terminal. Issue is when I try to ping 192.168.99.100 inside Ubuntu its now working so I am not able to connect mongo from there

Comment: Ubuntu is a different VM other than the one running docker? If so add the output of `ip addr show` to your question

Comment: Added Terminal Log

Comment: My Docker Is using NAT and Ubuntu is using Bridge Network

Comment: @Ashish451, there are multiple adapters to every VM, if you checking setting `Adapter 2` will be using `Host Only Network`. You need to add another adapter using `Adapter 3` or `Adapter 4` whichever is available

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152823/discussion-between-ashish451-and-tarun-lalwani).