# mongoimport Docker Failed: error connecting to the db server: no reachable servers

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoimport

I am trying to create a Docker container with MongoDB and import data into it. I have tried using the following dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo

# This will be created if it doesn't exist
WORKDIR /app/data/

# Copy dependency definitions
COPY mydata.csv .

ENTRYPOINT mongod

# Import data
RUN mongoimport --host=127.0.0.1 -d mydb -c reports --type csv --file mydata.csv --headerline
```

I get the following error:

```
Failed: error connecting to the db server: no reachable servers
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: have you found the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
mongoimport --host 127.0.0.1 --port <specifyPort> -d mydb -c reports --type csv --file mydata.csv --headerline
```

Comment: Is mongodb running inside the container? What port its running if not on 27017? You need to pass --port  explicitly if its not 27017

Comment: How can I know if mongodb is running inside the container? Sorry for the noob question, I am completely new to Docker...

Comment: docker ps -a, pickup a mongodb containers port from there

Comment: The point is that when I run the build command from docker (docker build -t mongotest .), the process stops because of the error mentioned above. When listing the containers I see three of them but with no ports attached to them...

Comment: whats the mongodb config look like? In the docker image? Whats the port specified?

Comment: I do not have any mongodb config file actually. I was hoping that just the dockerfile would be enough ?

Comment: check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45876216/connect-to-mongodb-running-inside-docker

Comment: Thank for the link, I needed to run mongod --smallfiles before using mongoimport!

Comment: glad to know that!