# Dockerfile > RUN mongoimport => Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, dockerfile

As a newbie of Docker, I tried to build a mongoDB Docker container containing some sample data by means of `docker-compose.yml` in the working directory.

My `mongo/Dockerfile` contains following code:

```
FROM mongo:latest
ADD shops.json /home/
RUN mongoimport --db masterdata --collection shops --file /home/shops.json
```

In the last line, sample data would be imported to mongoDB.

My `docker-compose.yml` contains the following code:

```
version: '3'
  services:
    mongo:
    build: mongo
    ports:
    - "27017:27017"
```

With the configuration above, I tried to build the MongoDB docker container and got error:

```
Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
```

This problem looks similar with [mongoimport Docker Failed: error connecting to the db server: no reachable servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47416987/mongoimport-docker-failed-error-connecting-to-the-db-server-no-reachable-serve), but I really tried every suggestion given in [mongoimport Docker Failed: error connecting to the db server: no reachable servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47416987/mongoimport-docker-failed-error-connecting-to-the-db-server-no-reachable-serve) and am never able to resolve this error.

So anyone can help on this?

Answer (score 2):

```
RUN mkdir -p /opt/acrc/config
COPY *.json /opt/acrc/config/
RUN mongod --fork --logpath=/tmp/mongodb.log && sleep 20 && \
  mongoimport -c=users -d=acrc --mode=upsert --file=/opt/acrc/config/users.json && \
  mongoimport -c=tasks -d=acrc --mode=upsert --file=/opt/acrc/config/tasks.json && \
  mongoimport -c=configs -d=acrc --mode=upsert --file=/opt/acrc/config/configs.json && \
  mongoimport -c=agentGroupConfigs -d=acrc --mode=upsert --file=/opt/acrc/config/agentGroupConfigs.json
```

Answer (score 1):

The mongo database is not started until you start a container of your image. The Dockerfile just takes care of the files and folders within the image but doesn't start any services.

To import a json into the database, you can write a bash script which will start the mongo services and import the json. You can set this script as entry script for your image.

Comment: why we need to do docker run if we are build our app using docker-compose here ?

Comment: I meant until a container is started. I have changed my answer.

Comment: @abskmj So in that case my way of adding the `RUN mongoimport` in the end of the Dockerfile is kinda wrong? meaning I should run `mongoimport` after installing the mongo container, right?

Comment: Yes, or you can add it as part of your start script for your docker image.